# rotating button titleLabel text

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want title on a button to looks like:

[image]

What I have done so far -in my table view cell- is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellJob") as!JobPostTbleCell
     cell.btnApply.titleLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2)
    cell.btnApply.titleLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    return cell

}
```

and I am getting this:

[image]

How to achieve the required output?

Comment: Assuming that the button it self is the orange one, which its height is more than its width, is it correct?

Comment: @AhmadF -yes its height is more than its width . button height is equal to cell height.

Comment: Just to make sure that I will provide a correct answer, your problem is: the title label is divided in two lines, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this code in cellForRowAt indexPath

```
 cell.btnApply.titleLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -(CGFloat.pi / 2))
    cell.btnApply.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    cell.btnApply.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 1
```

and change alignment of button from storyboard like this and it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set custom class for your button "RotatableButton"

```
@IBDesignable class RotatableButton: UIButton {
    @IBInspectable var angle:CGFloat = 0 {
        willSet {
            rotate(angle: newValue)
        }
    }
    func rotate(angle: CGFloat) {
        let radians = angle / 180.0 * CGFloat.pi
        let rotation = self.transform.rotated(by: radians)
        self.titleLabel?.transform = rotation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider that we have the following button:

[image]

As you can see, the width of the button is smaller than the title label width, but that's won't be applicable when rotating the height, it should appears with fully width (the height of the button is more than the label with even after rotating it).

By applying the following code:

```
myBtn.titleLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -(CGFloat.pi / 2))
myBtn.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
myBtn.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

The output would be:

[image]

Since my button is not in a table view cell, I implemented the above code in the `viewDidLoad()` method, which should also gives the desired output for a button in a cell...

Comment: thank you.. but it worked only when I apply .numberOfLines = 1 and .adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true but by this font size of text  gets smaller . I want font size same as a I define it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cell.btnApply.titleLabel?.transform = view.transform.rotated(by: .pi)
```

Comment: I also try view.transform.rotated(by: .pi/2)..but not working

Comment: Are you using swift 3?